# jxbrowser switch proxy at runtime

Tags: jxbrowser

It is posibble to switch proxy at runtime? For example, set a proxy, load a page and change a proxy, load another page. `BrowserContextParams.setProxyConfig()` does not work at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[JxBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) allows configuring proxy settings only during initialization and doesn't allow modifying them at runtime: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013067-working-with-proxy

**UPD:** In [6.15](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/topics/9000036612) we introduced functionality that allows modifying proxy settings at runtime.

Comment: Is there any way to archive this demand? Change system proxy?or use proxy pac? jdk1.8+ubuntu 16 gnome.

Comment: If you don't configure JxBrowser with custom proxy settings, JxBrowser will use system proxy settings by default. You can try updating system proxy settings and see if they are applied on the fly.